# I want to add my email account to Gmail and pickup IMAP mail

Tags: gmail, imap

I have googled and read many instructions about this. However, I cannot seem to make this work and need a little assistance. I will explain what I need to happen below:

My customer has a domain hosted by GoDaddy. It has POP3 email setup for multiple users.

She is responsible for managing 5 different email accounts for executives.

When she opens up Gmail, she can then choose to open any one of the 5 accounts that do *not* end with `@gmail.com` but rather with their domain.

They now have another new domain registered with GoDaddy.

It has 5 accounts set up as IMAP.

She would like to have the same scenario as above where she is able to open up Gmail, sign in with her new domain email account and then open the other new domain email accounts just like she does with the first domain mentioned above.

I have read through the Gmail instructions about adding another email account for Gmail to receive on...but, in the options area of Gmail it only states "add POP3 email account and the port..." There is no option for IMAP.

Support people at GoDaddy say that it can be done but, of course they offer no help to do this since it is Google.

On the first domain that is setup and working, I do see that the MX Records have been changed from pointing to GoDaddy and now point to Gmail. Makes since to me.

I have changed the new domains MX Records to point to Gmail, I checked for propogation and it is good but still cannot receive the email on Gmail like she wants to.

Any help would be appreciated! Step by step instructions are helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This has been a long requested function for Gmail, however, Google has never added support for this.  They only support POP3, your client will have to setup POP3 to use Gmail as you intend.